# What happens with "nested" property bindings that are null?

Tags: silverlight

Example:

Text="{Binding Path=CurrentPerson.FirstName}"

What happens when CurrentPerson is null? Is this an execption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not throw an exception, it will just fail silently when the expression is evaluated at runtime.

You can use the TargetNullValue property to provide a value when the source is null:

```
<TextBox Width="150"
     Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource object}, 
     Path=PropertyB, BindingGroupName=bindingGroup, 
     TargetNullValue=please enter a string}" />
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx

Also, you can use FallbackValue when the property path is invalid:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BadPath, FallbackValue='Invalid Path'}"/>
```